# Can't connect the Hololens to a Bluetooth Low Energy device

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, bluetooth, hololens

For a project I'm working on, I need to read data from a BluetoothLE module (HM-10). I need to read and use this data from a Unity-application. To connect and read data I'm building a plugin for Unity using Visual Studio 2017. I can get a list of BluetoothLE devices using:

```
 string[] requestedProperties = { "System.Devices.Aep.DeviceAddress", "System.Devices.Aep.IsConnected" };

        deviceWatcher =
                    DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher(
                            BluetoothLEDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromPairingState(false),
                            requestedProperties,
                            DeviceInformationKind.AssociationEndpoint);
```

Connecting to a device seems to work as well. I use:

```
  BluetoothLEDevice btDevice = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(device.Id);
```

Next, I want to read the data that this device is sending. I understand I need to collect the services and characteristics next before I can read this data. But for some reason I can't await the services. I get an error using this:`var gattservices = await btDevice.GetGattServicesAsync();`
The error reads:

> Unable to cast object of type 'Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.BluetoothLEDevice' to type 'Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.IBluetoothLEDevice3'

Am I using the wrong methods to get my results?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UWP Bluetooth LE InvalidCastException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44188667/uwp-bluetooth-le-invalidcastexception)

Comment: No, I have followed the exact same steps as described in the link you are referring to, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Hi Erik,
Did you find your answer?Actually I am also looking for some plugin which will connect the hololens to bluetooth device.

Comment: Hello Nishant, yes I have finally created a working connection between the hololens and my bluetooth LE device. I'll submit my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found how I can get all services and the characteristics per service. By creating a GattDevice I can get the services with `GattDevice.GattServices`.
When I found the correct GattDeviceService, I can get the Characteristics with:

```
GattService s = new GattService(GattDeviceService)
GattCharacteristic.GetCharacteristics(s)
```

Comment: Does this work on the HoloLens? If yes could you send me an example?

Comment: It does work on Hololens, I can not give you an easy example. If you can retrieve a list of nearby devices, you can Create a GattDevice and connect to the service you want to connect to using the code above.

Comment: Yes with the new OS update on HoloLens this works. With the first HL OS it did not work as the interfaces were there but not implemented.